# Highslide does not expand images on Wordpress

Tags: highslide

I am trying to integrate Highslide with my Wordpress site without plugins. I have changed the hs.graphicsDir variables to:

```
graphicsDir : 'http://hyohanpark.com/wp-content/themes/Noir/highslide/graphics/'
```

The code within my  tags also read:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/highslide/highslide-with-gallery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/highslide/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/highslide/highslide.css" />
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/highslide/highslide-ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Here is what the code looks like when I'm displaying an image to be opened using highslide:

```
<div class="highslide-gallery">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="http://hyohanpark.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/IMG_0042.png" class="highslide" 
        onclick="return hs.expand(this, config1 )">
    <img src="http://hyohanpark.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/IMG_0042.png" width="230" height="154" alt=""/>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div style="clear:both"></div></div>
```

Everything seems to be working; however, once you click an image, instead of expanding, it opens the image's URL instead as if it was a regular link to the image.

Any help to get the images to expand properly is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there’s an inconsistency between the `onclick` for your images and the content of your *highslide.config.js* file.

When you're using `config1` in the `onclick` you also need a corresponding configuration object in your *highslide.config.js* file:

```
var config1 = {
    //configurations for the images
};
```

The configuration object can be empty, but it would typically contain settings for the gallery.

Comment: Thanks! the var config1 was missing somehow, so I added that portion in. It still didn't work, but I ended up going to the advanced settings for the image in wordpress and added "highslide" to the "Link Rel" box. That got it to work!